# CAKEPHP2.7.5 が突然エラーが出るようになった

Tags: cakephp

CAKEPHPのシステムを開発し2年ほど運用していましたが
突然下記エラーが出るようになりました。

環境
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
PHP 5.4.27
CAKEPHP2.7.5

```
Warning (512): _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'cake_dev_ja' to File cache [CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 328]
Warning (512): _cake_model_ cache was unable to write 'default_*****_list' to File cache [CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 328]
```

サーバの中には複数のCAKEPHP（同じバージョン）がありますが
問題なく動いています。
念のため
新規環境を作っても下記メッセージが出てきます。

```
Warning (512): _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'cake_dev_ja' to File cache [CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 328]
```

app/tmp/cache/models
app/tmp/cache/persistent
app/tmp/cache/views
のパーミッションも確認しましたが777です。

何がおかしくなったのでしょうか？
何卒よろしくお願いします

Answer (score 0, accepted):

私も似た現象が出た時があります。
DISK容量が不足していたのが問題でした。
DISKの空きが十分ありますか？